# How can I remove 2 separate portions of a URL using mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this unfortunate URL:

```
dom.tld/library/Photography/index.php?cmd=image&sfpg=2021/*IMG_3468.jpg
dom.tld/library/Photography/index.php?sfpg=2021/*
```

This should look like this

```
dom.tld/library/Photography/2021/IMG_3468.jpg
dom.tld/library/Photography/2021/
```

Essentially, I want to remove `index.php?cmd=image&sfpg=` and the asterisk `*` before the filename.

The folder structure looks like this:

```
root /var/www/domain.tld/main/library/Photography -> tree -a
.
|-- .htaccess
|-- index.php
|-- _GalData
|   |-- info
|   |   |-- 2018
|   |   |   |-- April
|   |   |   |   |-- _sfpg_dir
|   |   |   |   `-- image.png
|   |   |   |-- _sfpg_dir
|   |   |   `-- image.png
|   |   |-- 2019
|   |   |   |-- _sfpg_dir
|   |   |   `-- image.png
|   |   `-- _sfpg_dir
|   `-- thumb
|       |-- 2018
|       |   |-- April
|       |   |   `-- image.jpg
|       |   `-- image.jpg
|       `-- 2019
|           `-- image.jpg
`-- synced
    |-- 2018
    |   |-- April
    |   |   `-- image.jpg
    |   `-- image.jpg
    `-- 2019
        `-- image.jpg
```

The real images are stored in `synced/` and `_GalData/` is generated by index.php
The main website resides at `/var/www/domain.tld/main/index.html`

Comment: Following your update... presumably `folder/image.jpg` then refers to the file-path within the `synced` subdirectory? And you wish to serve the "real images" directly? Presumably  `/var/www/domain.tld/main` the document-root directory?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure this is the best way to do it, but given the following folder structure

```
user@instance-apache:/var/www/html$ tree -a
.
├── .htaccess
├── index.html
└── library
    └── photography
        └── folder
            └── image.jpg
```

and this content of the .htaccess file [**UPDATED**]

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*\=(.*)\*(.*)
RewriteRule (.*/)index.php /$1%1%2 [QSD]
```

apache should makes

http://127.0.0.1/library/photography/index.php?cmd=image&sfpg=folder/*image.jpg

into

http://127.0.0.1/library/photography/folder/image.jpg

Comment: This works in an htaccess tester but it makes the whole photography folder return 404 if I put it on my actual site.

Comment: error.log shows this

`applying pattern '/index.php' to uri 'library/Photography/index.php'`

`RewriteCond: input='cmd=image&sfpg=2022/*IMG_1991.jpg' pattern='.*\\=(.*?)\\*(.*)' => matched`

`rewrite 'library/Photography/index.php' -> '/2022/IMG_1991.jpg'`

`discarding query string`

I don't know what any of this means

Comment: changed the code block, should be better now, hopefully. I believe the htaccess tester (which I also used to validate), doesn't use the root level .htaccess

Comment: Thank you. I think I found a problem in the general approach, however. The actual files do not reside where the link would imply. Please see my updated question. The URL is made up by index.php.

Answer (score 1):

In the `.htaccess` file located in the subdirectory at `/library/photography/.htaccess` you can do something like the following using mod_rewrite to internally rewrite the request to the desired URL.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)cmd=image(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)sfpg=([^&*]+)\*([^&]+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %1%2 [QSD,L]
```

The first *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) simply confirms that the `cmd=image` URL parameter is present anywhere in the query string.

The second *condition* captures the parts of the `sfpg` URL parameter value surrounding the `*` character (which needs to be backslash-escaped when used *outside* of a regex character class in order to negate its special meaning). These are then available in the `%1` and `%2` backreferences respectively and used in the *substitution* string (2nd argument of the `RewriteRule` directive) is construct a *relative* file-path (ie. relative to the `/library/photography/` subdirectory that contains the `.htaccess` file).

There URL parameters can appear in any order. eg. `?sfpg=folder/*image.jpg&cmd=image` would also successfully match. And there can be additional URL parameters, which are discarded.

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag removes the original query string from the rewritten request (not that it really matters for an internal rewrite).

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteRule /index.php /
> ```

This doesn't really make sense as an internal rewrite, since both `/index.php` and `/` should return the same resource. (This would ordinarily be implemented as an external redirect in order to resolve any SEO issues with regards to duplicate content.)

---

**UPDATE:**

> I think I found a problem in the general approach, however. The actual files do not reside where the link would imply. Please see my updated question.

If I understand your update correctly, the "real file" that you wish to serve is stored in the `synced` subdirectory and the `sfpg` URL parameter refers to the file-path within that subdirectory (less the `*`)? (Which is all within the `/library/Photography` subdirectory, including the `.htaccess` file. Or at least the `.htaccess` file that we are working on here.)

In which case, you would only seem to need to modify the `RewriteRule` directive by prefixing the *substitution* string with `synced/`. For example:

```
:
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ synced/%1%2 [QSD,L]
```

(Everything else remains unchanged from the rule above, at the top of my answer.)

Comment: Thank you. I think I found a problem in the general approach, however. The actual files do not reside where the link would imply. Please see my updated question. The URL is made up by index.php.

Comment: @Apver2t5kM I've updated my answer following your update.

Comment: This is very, very close! If I manually enter synced/folder/image.jpg it works. When I go to photography/ through the link found in library/, it still shows the old undesired link. I guess it's not within the scope of mod_rewrite to serve the correct link, but instead the php file? Additionally is it possible to hide the synced/ folder from the URL?

Comment: I updated the post to clarify what I want the new URLs to look like.